# How to evaluate the number of pairing situation given some objects?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I need to evaluate the number of pairing situation for K object. Notice that no pair available is also counted. In the example below, if two objects are paired together then they are group by curly bracket {}

For example:

If $K=2$ and we  have to object $A,B$ then there is 2 pairing situation A pair B and no pairing at all

If $K=3$ we then have 4 situation that is ({A,B},C),(A,{B,C}),({A,C},B) and no pairing at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you are going to end up with $n<K/2$ pairs. One way to count them is the following: arrange all objects in a row. Objects in places 1,2 are paired together. Also object in places 3,4 and so on, until places 2n-1,2n. The rest $K-2n$ objects are not paired.

We count here too many things: permutations of unpaired objects don't matter, and there are $(K-2n)!$ of them. Internal permutations of each pair don't matter, and we have $2!$ for each pair. Also, the permutations of the $n$ pairs themselves don't matter, and we have $n!$ of them.

To conclude, the number of ways to do it is $\tfrac{K!}{2^n n! (K-2n)!}$ and the total number of pairings is

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{K/2} \tfrac{K!}{2^n n! (K-2n)!}$$

I'm not sure if it sums up to something nicer or not.

Tests:

$K=2$: $\tfrac{2!}{2^0 0! (2-0)!}+\tfrac{2!}{2^1 1! (2-2)!}=2$

$K=3$: $\tfrac{3!}{2^0 0! (3-0)!}+\tfrac{3!}{2^1 1! (3-2)!}=4$

$K=4$: $\tfrac{4!}{2^0 0! (4-0)!}+\tfrac{4!}{2^1 1! (4-2)!}+\tfrac{4!}{2^2 2! (4-4)!}=10$

Comment: Yes, your answer is correct but I was unable to understand it. 

Could you please elaborate more:

Why do we have to divide $K!$ by ${2^n}n!\left( {K - 2n} \right)!$ ?

And also what is ${2^n}$ describe ?

Comment: You take all the permutations ($K!$) and divide them by permutations that represent the same pairing. $2^n$ represents that in each pairing, the order of the two objects in the pair do not matter (AB=BA). The other terms represent the fact that the order of the pairs don't matter and the order of the unpaired objects don't matter.

Comment: So the physical meaning of $2^n$ is the number of way to arrange the internal object of the pair ?

Comment: The denominator is the number of ways to write the same pairing. Consider ${A,B},C$. This pairing can be written as $AB|C$ or $BA|C$. I don't want to count them twice, so I divide by $2$. This is the $2^n$. The rest are similar.

Comment: Yes, it's the number of ways to arrange K objects / the number of ways that are the same pairing.